# Doctrine optimize n+2 queries

Tags: sql, performance, doctrine

I saw multiple articles about how to optimize n+1 queries in PHP Doctrine (eg how to load a collection before doing a loop over its elements). However, optimizing n+2 requests seems less straighforward, I'm not sure Doctrine has got the feature I need to handle this case nicely.

I work on a little application, where I implemented a history feature.
Let's take Redmine's ticket HTML page as an example.
We have a ticket id, we want to display :

- the ticket's data
- its history (saturday at 5PM, Ted did modification #5)
- its detailed history (modification #5 consists of 2 changes (2 rows in db) : past time 5 => 10 hours, remaining time : 8 => 2 hours).
- other datas, like comments, etc.

So we want to be able to build a list of history resume, each containing a list of history details in the html view (a list of lists).
Ex :

```
Ticket 37 : Title = "I need this feeeture", assigned time = "50 hours"
- History #1, Monday at 4am by Paul Gent
  - Detail #1 : ticket title modified : "I need this feeeture" => "I need this feature"
  - Detail #2 : ticket assigned time set to "5 hours"
- History #2 : Monday at 5 am by Paul Gent
  - Detail #1 : ticket assigned time modified : "5 hours" => "50 hours"
- History #3 : ...
```

Is it possible to load all this data in the same $ticket object, using multiple queries ?
How can I load both ticket main data, history and its details without having a combinatory explosion in SQL results ?
The 3 queries I'd like Doctrine to generate are the following :

```
1) Select * from ticket t where t.id = XXX;
2) Select * from ticket_history h where h.ticket_id = XXX
3) Select * from ticket_history_detail d where d.ticket_history_id in (5, 9, 10, 18, 66, 95)
or 
3) Select d.* from ticket_history_detail d
   inner join ticket_history h on d.ticket_history_id = h.history_id
   where h.ticket_id = XXX
```

I want to avoid the next query, because it generates way too many rows :

```
1) Select t.*,h.*,d.* from ticket t
   left join ticket_history h on h.ticket_id = t.id
   left join ticket_history_detail d on d.ticket_history_id = h.history_id
   where t.id = XXX
```

Your help is welcome !

Comment: I can't see which unwanted rows can the second query return. May be you mean too many columns?

Comment: Yep you are right. If I add another join, like ticket followers ( people who want to  know about ticket evolutions ), then if I have many followers and many history details,  the  request is bad because it returns : 20 followers * 50 history details = 1000 rows instead of 70 rows. The returned data is dupplicated